# How big are floating-point calculation variations across modern processors?

Tags: floating-point, fixed-point

For a game I want to implement fully deterministic replay functionality which replicate the same results even if the generated replay files are used on another system. It will also be used for multiplayer and cheat detection.

I am aware however that fully deterministic math is unlikely to work as floating points calculations have small variations.

To solve that I use fixed-point math that all works well already, but when it comes to the often-used sine, cosine and comparable functions, coming up with own implementions feels like I am wasting too much performance as they are used very very often periodically.

However I am wondering, as I only need 8 bits for the fractional part of a number, if this all-selfmade approach is really wise. If the differences across processors regarding sine, cosine and so on is **always** way below my accuracy of 1/256 anyway, I could just use the regular sine function which returns a floating point number and convert it to my fixed point number.
The conversation would be like this for the sine as an example:

```
const double factor = pi/512;
int x = 512; //example which is equal to pi
int q = round(256*sin(factor*x)); //= 0
```

I am targeting computers that are able to run 3d games and are not older than 15 years. I intend to to do multithreading if this matters as well.

But to do that I need to know the worst cases of how much the sine/cosine can vary. Ideally including GPUs as a potential computing unit. Can someone point me towards useful sources?

---

*EDIT1:*

Staying at the example of sine, I calculated all fixed point numbers within 0<=x<=256 (which is from 0 to pi/2) and see how close the resulting, unrounded number is to the edge of where the rounding would "tip".

The worst case happens at x=108, which results in q=~157.4992872 on an Intel i5-3470 processor. Can a variation be large enough to tip this to 157.5?

I also consider to use a custom round function for each math function. In the case of sine and cosine I would round at 0.465972289906148 instead of 0.5 because this value is within one of the biggest gaps of all possible values. Without the factor of 256 outside the sine, the value is in a ±0.00004324 gap that is much more tolerant than it'd be at 0.5. (Which is in a +0.00000273 / -0.00000139 gap)

Comment: All x86-64bit CPUs should run the same IEEE754-math (there are some options regarding rounding but they are the same on every processor). Precision of higher level functions is more a question about the underlying library. You may try [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/) if you want to be absolutely sure about reproducibility.

Comment: Even implementations that are lax about IEEE 754 compliance are still going to give reasonable accuracy, in that the error will be in terms of some small number of 'ulps', or 'units in the last place' (i.e. bit/digit). Since any number you're working with will have more than 8 bits of fractional part (`float16_t` things maybe excepted), you should be ok rounding to a fixed-point number without worrying about imprecision below 1/256

Comment: @PhilMiller This is what I am thinking too, but did you notice the EDIT I did to my question? Even the smallest variation could make a change within my accuracy. I already think about setting a custom rounding edge that is close to .5 but also in a gap between local possible values and not too close to one.

Comment: @chtz: Re “All x86-64bit CPUs should run the same IEEE754-math”: IEEE-754 contains specifications for your “higher level functions,” so you should qualify that to the elementary operations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and square root.

Comment: Re EDIT1: Huh? If 0≤x≤255 corresponds to 0 to π/2, then presumably x encodes π/2•x/255. Then 148 represents π/2•148/255 ≈ .9116778681. The sine of that is about .7905324123, which is encoded by .7905324123•255/(π/2) ≈ 128,3334839138. How do you get −157.4992872? Your code suggests the encoding actually uses 256, not 255, but then x encodes π/2•x/256, 148 represents .9081166264, the sine is about .7883464276, and that is encoded by 128.4804923654.

Comment: Your code also suggests you might be using a different fixed-point format for the results, as it multiplies by 256 after taking the sine, rather than 256/(π/2). But then we would have .7883464276•256, which is about 201.8166784.

Comment: Incidentally, there are a number of other questions and answers on Stack Overflow about floating-point determinism. Have you reviewed them? See [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfloating-point%5D+determinism) to start.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right, the range is actually 0<=x<=256 for o..pi/2. I fixed that.
Also I accidentally copied a result from my cos table. So the correct x for sine is 108, not 148. Thank you for pointing that out.
I reviewed numerous questions about that but I'll do that again, I think I used less fitting search terms.

Comment: If you only need ~8 bits of input, you can just use a table instead. If the table is identical between the target architectures, then the computation is reproducible.

Comment: @EOF That'd be a 256B table which needs some more arithmetic operations to "unwrap" the use of symmetry. I don't think there is any gain unless my idea in the OP turns out not working withing the range of processor variations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The results of the search so far teach me that deterministic float-point math is possible, but I can't see me monitoring all the possible breaking points of that. The information of how much careless (in terms of determinism) use of floating point math (like I intend to do in my code example) can vary was nowhere measured yet.

Comment: @Urben If the table is only 256 byte in size, that'd almost certainly be smaller than the amount of memory using a floating-point library will add to the running program (since it needs to map at least a whole memory page, which is typically 4096 bytes). So your binary *may* be smaller without the table, but the running program image will be larger. If you statically link the float library, you'll have a larger binary as well.

Comment: Oh I did not know that! I thought such basic things like float sine are implemented as hardware gates that don't need additional libary loaded.

Comment: @Urben Most floating-point hardware only implements a few fundamental operations (`+, -, *, /, <=>, sqrt, abs`), sometimes a few useful utility operations (approx. `1/x`, approx `1/(x*x`), approx. `sqrt`, `fma`), with complex operations computed in software. A few old CISC architectures (x86, 68k) have sin/cos/asin/acos/exp/log in "hardware" (actually microcode), but for x86 it's only in the legacy x87 FPU, not in the current SSE/AVX vector FPU. Also, the "hardware" implementations are slow and sometimes inaccurate, so they tend to need software support, which requires linking more code.